# Handling circular entity references with Migrate

Tags: entities, migrations

I am using [Migrate D2D](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) on a Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 migration right now.

I have three types: type1, type2, type3.  Each of the three types has a entityreference field on it, which is configured to be able to point to all three types.  This means that there can be circular references, and when a particular node is being migrated, the destination node may not exist yet and could potentially be any of the three types.

My migration class looks like this:

```
class MyNodeMigration extends DrupalNode6Migration {
  public function __construct(array $arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);

    $this->addFieldMapping('field_legacy_nid', 'nid');

    $this->addFieldMapping('field_the_reference', 'field_the_reference')
      ->sourceMigration(array('type1', 'type2', 'type3');
  }
}

$node_arguments = array(
  array(
    'class_name' => 'MyNodeMigration',
    'description' => 'type1',
    'machine_name' => 'type1',
    'source_type' => 'type1',
    'destination_type' => 'type1',
    'dependencies' => array('roles', 'users'),
  ),

  array(
    'class_name' => 'MyNodeMigration',
    'description' => 'type2',
    'machine_name' => 'type2',
    'source_type' => 'type2',
    'destination_type' => 'type2',
    'dependencies' => array('roles', 'users'),
  ),

  array(
    'class_name' => 'MyNodeMigration',
    'description' => 'type3',
    'machine_name' => 'type3',
    'source_type' => 'type3',
    'destination_type' => 'type3',
    'dependencies' => array('roles', 'users'),
  ),
);

$common_node_arguments = $common_arguments + array(
  'user_migration' => 'users',
);

foreach ($node_arguments as $arguments) {
  $arguments = array_merge_recursive($arguments, $common_node_arguments);

  Migration::registerMigration($arguments['class_name'], $arguments['machine_name'], $arguments);
}
```

When I run the migrations, most nodes are fine, but I get a decent amount of Stubs **(*)** created.  Some of the destination nodes have the entityreference pointing to these Stub nodes.  The source nodes are fine.

What I have uncovered is that the bundle on the destination nodes that are being made as stubs are incorrect, and look like they are all type1.  A node of the proper type does end up being created, but it never gets set as the entityreference target.

Another way to explain this is that I end up with

- node: nid=123, type=type1
- node: nid=234, type=type1, field_the_reference=123
- node: nid=345, type=type2

where it should be

- node: nid=234, type=type1, field_the_reference=345
- node: nid=345, type=type2

How do I handle this situation?

**(*)**: a "Stub" in the context of this question here refers to a node which is created for the purpose of being a reference target, but does not get its data initially. The term is used throughout the Migrate documentation and source code.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem has to do with how [stubs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1013506) are handled in Migrate, and is related to a [known issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1096132).

In short, when the destination can be one of several content types, the migration doesn't know what content type to create the stub as in a generic way.

My current workaround for this is to prevent stubs from being created:

```
abstract class MyNodeMigration extends DrupalNode6Migration {
  ... 

  protected function createStub(Migration $migration, array $source_id) {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

When the migration runs, stubs don't get created, but the entity reference fields in my destinations also don't get populated.

I then manually reset the highwater mark

```
db_update('migrate_status')
  ->fields(array('highwater' => 0))
  ->condition(...)
  ->execute();
```

and then rerun the migrations.  Since the destination nodes exists, the entity reference fields can be populated properly.

Comment: I would absolutely love to have a better solution than this if anyone would like to add an answer.